Why all files marked as unversioned files after I deleted the file which named ":" on MacOS
For any reason, there's a committed file ":" in the project root directory on my branch. I tried to delete it but then all the files in my project was marked as unversioned files.
I tried to search answer but not found any discussion.
It happened on the MacOS and when I saw the file in finder, it showed as file named "/". So I just guess, the git marked it as the root directory and when I deleted it, it was tracked as root, so seems like every file was deleted, and added again.
And then I learned that ":" was the file separator of macOS. Looks like my guess might be correct, but I'm still confused how it works in git.
I think git generates a hash value for each file and compares the hash value to determine whether changes have occurred, then why every file would be marked changed and unversioned.

PS: I just found that this problem will occur only when I delete the file from Android Studio but not in finder, so there might be some problem when AS process deleting operation

This is downright nightmarish. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Does running git rm ':' on the command-line have the expected effect? It sounds like something is seeing : as equivalent to ./ and running something like git rm -r ./
